# Firebase Cloud Functions onUpdate triggers returns unreliable timestamps to Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple function in Cloud Functions that is triggered when any update occurs on my "clients" location in my Cloud Firestore database.

Problem is when I update the data once it changes the lastUpdated child of the document that was updated to seconds 1572841408099 and then I change the child again, it always reverts lastUpdated to a Cloud Firestore Timestamp that is for the time: "November 3, 2019 at 9:44:16 PM UTC-6" regardless of what time it actually is.

How do I get the following code to reliably return what time the data was updated?

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const clientUpdatedTask = functions.firestore.document('clients/{clientId}').onUpdate((change: any, context: any) => {
    const before = change.before.data();
    const after = change.after.data();
    const timeEdited = Date.now();
    if(before.lastUpdated.seconds !== after.lastUpdated.seconds) {
        return 'The Time Did Not Change. No Need To Run Update!';
    } else {
        return change.after.ref.update({'lastUpdated' : timeEdited}, {merge: true});
    }
});
```

Why does it revert back to a regular timestamp for a time in the past upon a second implication? Furthermore, why does it jump between the seconds and the timestamp on each update?

Comment: I am curious why you are overriding the types of `change` and `context` to `any`.  They have well defined types in TypeScript via the type bindings in firebase-functions.

Comment: I removed any and got deploy errors that they weren’t defined in my console. Documentation does not provide any offerings on how to declare them. Also, I still can’t explain why the time stamps are not reliable.

Comment: You shouldn't have to declare anything.  The types are all provided by the firebase-functions module.  As far as I know, the documentation is all correct.  I do this all the time - something might be wrong with your setup.

Comment: As far as the cloud functions setup? All I did was use the firebase cli to init a project. Do you use TSLint? Should I disable that?

Comment: I use everything.  The defaults should all work out of the box.  Make sure your CLI is up to date.  If you have reproduction steps that always cause a failure, please file a bug report on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools